# Using the variance and expectation of the Bernoulli random variable to calculate the variance and expectation of the binomial random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

So,  I saw on this video that:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fqkQRjcR1M

One way,  in which we can calculate the expectation and variance of the Binomial random variable is by using the Bernoulli random variable. Here is a screenshot I took:

[image]

I am confused because this seems like a misrepresentation to me. So when we calculate the expected value of the Binomial random variable what we want is the expected value of the number of successes correct? So we are calculating the weighted average of the number of successes. But in the picture given above it seems to me that each of $U_{1}, U_{2}....U_{n}$ is only calculating the expected value of getting a success on the $n^{th}$ trial. How is this at all similar to what we are originally trying to calculate which is the expected value of the NUMBER of wins?

Comment: This property is called linearity of expectation: https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/

Comment: I am not confused about the linearity of expectation part

Comment: Are you confused about why $U_1 + \dots + U_n$ is the number of successes then?

Comment: Yeah, like I thought each of the different U values only account for success in the Uth trial

Comment: Yes, that’s why their sum is the total number of successes over all trials, more or less by definition.